# How can i improve this code? (implode/explode/unserialize)

Tags: php

Im not satisfied im doing this the best way possible. Im taking serialized code from database column *location*. Im assuming that i have to implode the serialized data and then explode it because when i just use implode i cant access the entries in *counties* so i used explode. Im sure there's a better approach?

```
$adid = $_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM ad WHERE id = '$adid'";
$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$ad = mysqli_fetch_array($data);



 //retrieve serialized data containing county id's
    $counties = explode(" ", implode(" ", unserialize($ad['location'])));

for ($i = 0; $i <= count($counties); $i++) {
echo getCounty($counties[$i]); //getCounty: enter county id and return county name
}


FYI: $ad['location'] = a:2:{i:0;s:1:"2";i:1;s:2:"20";}
```

Comment: take a look at [ `foreach()` ](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) --- and don't explode/implode the same thing.... also describing your data would help in understanding the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use implode(), when you have a serialized string, unserialize() only does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

`unserialize()` should return an array.  Why are you imploding and then exploding?